# linear transformation qualifications

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

If $T(x) = Ax + b$, is $T$ a linear transformation? I don't quite understand the relation between $T$ and $A$, is $T$ just $A$ with an added or removed dimension? I know the qualifications for having a transformation to be linear where $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$ & $T(cu) = cT(u)$, but I don't see where the $A$ comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

Only if $b=0$.  Otherwise $T$ is affine.

It should be clear from the properties of matrix multiplication that $T(x) = Ax$ is linear (i.e. it satisfies both of those properties) for any matrix $A$.

But this is only one type of linear transformation.  An important type, granted, but still there are other linear transformations.  For example, $I(f) = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ is another linear transformation.  If you've taken calculus, this should also be easy to prove.